# Should I make a mutex (or lock) for writing to LiteDatabase?

Tags: locking, mutex, ioexception, litedb

I am writing considerably many data to the LiteDatabase.
Fortunately there is only one UserCollection in the database.
I am not sure there would be a conflict when there are several write accesses at the same time.
Practically, there were some IOExceptions when I accessed the database more frequently.
Should I make a mutex(lock) manually to prevent this?
Or LiteDatabase already support it?

LiteDB-vNext will resolve this but it is not released yet.
No IOExceptions should be.
I think I need to make my own lock for writing access.
And, need to wait unlocking for next writing access.

Comment: Depends. LiteDB already does Reader-Writer locking _per collection_. If that's enough for you, then it's enough. Maybe you can brake one huge collection down to several, so you have much less probability of collisions ... you give not nearly enough information to suggest anything, though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
I will try to make read/write lock when I need it.
Now I am concerning about another problem.
Is LiteDB being maintained still? I could not see any activities on git and chat.
I tried to ask them directly but could not get any reply. 
I would like to use LiteDB which is healthy and being maintained regulary.
Also I would like to know the estimated release date of LiteDB-vNext.
I would be very grateful if you could let me know about it.
Thank you again for your advice.

Comment: What do you mean? Latest Release was on July, 21 ... vNext is just for Tests / Beta of the upcoming Release.